# How to merge all CSV files in a directory to a single CSV file

Tags: f#

I'm trying to merge all CSV files in a directory to a single CSV file. When I ran the code below I get the following error:

System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\james\Desktop\Name\mergedCsvFile.csv' because it is being used by another process.'

```
open System.IO

let path = @"C:\Users\james\Desktop\Name\"
let csvfiles = Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.csv",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
let csvOutput = File.Create(path + "mergedCsvFile.csv")

csvfiles |> Array.map (fun file -> File.OpenRead(file).CopyTo(csvOutput))
```

I know this has something to do with `use` and `using` to release resources, but I have tried  these keywords in various places to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in that the issue is that files need to be properly closed and that this is done using the `use` keyword (which ensures that the `Dispose` is called when the object gets out of scope).

In this case, you can use the following. Note that I also replaced your `Array.map` with ordinary `for` loop, because you do not need to collect an array with results - you just want to run some imperative action (`Array.iter` would work too)

```
open System.IO

let path = @"C:\temp\csv\" // " (to fix stackoverflow formatting)

let copyAll path = 
  let csvfiles = Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.csv",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
  use csvOutput = File.Create(path + "mergedCsvFile.csv")
  for fileName in csvfiles do
    use fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName)
    fileStream.CopyTo(csvOutput)

copyAll path
```

You need `use` for `csvOutput` (which remains in scope as you iterate over the individual files) and for `fileStream` (which reamins in scope only during a single iteration of the for loop).

I also moved the entire code to `copyAll` function, because `use` works only inside local scopes (not top-level code in a script or module).

Finally, note that you need to correctly handle headers (if all your files have headers, skip them) and end of file (if there is no line break at the end of file, the first line of the second file will be appended right after the end of the last line of the previous file). In other words, it may be easier to do this using the pair of methods `File.ReadLines` and `File.AppendAllLines`.

Answer (score 0):

```
open System.IO

let path = @"C:\temp\csv\" // "
let fileName = "bronzeMerged.csv"
let header = "First,Middle,Last"

// Combine all CSV files in folder (except existing merged file which is deleted)
// with single header at top row of merged file.
let copyAll path fileName header = 
  File.Delete(path + fileName)
  let csvfiles = Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.csv",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
  let lines = seq { for file in csvfiles do
                      yield! File.ReadLines(file) 
                      |> Seq.where (fun x -> x <> header)}
  let linesWithHeader = Seq.append (seq {header}) lines
  File.AppendAllLines(path + fileName, linesWithHeader)

copyAll path fileName header
```